# Visual Studio Online: Multiple build controllers - how to add a new build controller

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops, automated-tests

I have multiple projects hosted on Visual Studio Online (Formerly TFS Service)

For one of my solutions, I have created a hosted build controller that runs **xUnit** to run all my unit tests. This works fine as everytime I check in my code, Continuous Integration kicks in, building my solution and runs my tests.

This is the build controller popup in **Solution A** (from VS2012)

[image]

In the Properties page:

[image]

Now I'm trying to use **nUnit** for another **Solution B**, but I can't seem to figure how I can create another build controller. When I open the build controller window in **Solution B**, I see the exact same thing that I see in **Solution A** and I can't find an "Add" option.

How can I have multiple build controllers so that I can use different test frameworks for different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just use one Build Controller that has access to both NUnit and XUnit assemblies.  Why not change the path to custom assemblies to: $/Asis.Ess.BuildController/

Then your builds can use both Xunit or Nunit assemblies and no need to have multiple build controllers and/or agents.