# How to setup Continuous Integration in Visual Studio Online with Git and Nunit

Tags: git, continuous-integration, visual-studio-2013, nunit, azure-devops

I've setup a Visual Studio Online account and chose Git for source control. I'm using NUnit and Moq for my Unit tests and I have my solution in Visual Studio 2013.

When CI kicks in the tests never run, instead I get the following warning

> "No test found. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors,
>   platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again."

I'm a bit lost here, I have no idea how to setup the "test discoverers & executors" etc.

What I did try was to add nunit and moq as custom assemblies as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826673/visual-studio-online-multiple-build-controllers-how-to-add-a-new-build-contro). That did not work.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23280749/826832

Comment: @klings Thanks! Tried it and it worked. Write down your answer here and I'll updvote and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @klings, installing the NUnit Test Adapter for VS2012 and VS2013 NuGet package solved my problem.

[**NUnit Test Adapter for VS2012 and VS2013**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/)

Comment: Passersby using Visual Studio Online build definitions, in the Visual Studio Test build step: **1.** Note that you may also need to use the "*Test Assembly*" field to properly match your test dlls. **2.** You may also need to provide the "*Path to Custom Test Adapters*", "`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages`" if you're using NuGet.  See [here](https://nocture.dk/2015/06/19/xunit-or-nunit-with-visual-studio-online-build/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this answer 
[Visual Studio Online CI Nunit Tests not found during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027235/visual-studio-online-ci-nunit-tests-not-found-during-build)

and also here
http://walkingthestack.blogspot.gr/2013/04/using-nunit-for-your-tests-in-team.html

Basically you need to provide tfs with the necessary dlls (which have to be fetched from a standard TFS repository since git does not support such functionality yet)